# Sails js policies not working

Tags: javascript, sails.js, policies

I have written a basic policies in Sails js.

in app/config/policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {
   '*': 'sessionAuth'
};
```

in app/api/policies/sessionAuth.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
console.log('reach');

  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  }


  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

But when i am requesting some URL, 'reach' is not printing in console and this basic policies is not working. It is going to that controller's action which is define in route.js.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your policies.js file :

You can try this

```
module.exports.policies = {
    //Your controller
    UserController: {
        '*': 'sessionAuth'
    }
};
```

Comment: Why? This seems to be valid config due to http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies#?to-apply-a-policy-to-all-actions-that-are-not-explicitly-mapped

Comment: Glen swift is correct !!. Problem was nested controller. Now its working.